# Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications - Find $A^3$ if $A = \{a\}$ and if $A = \{0, a\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Find $A^3$ if $A = \{a\}$ and if $A = \{0, a\}$

I am doing some homework for my Discrete Mathematics class and I have run across this question that hasn't been discussed in my lectures, so I was wondering if anyone here could assist me by explaining the problem and how to derive an answer?

Comment: I would imagine it means $A^3 = A \times A \times A = \{((x,y,z) | x,y,z \in A \}$. There are nine elements in total.

Comment: So then would {a} equal (x, y, z)?

Comment: I made a mistake above, there are 8 elements if $A$ has two elements, there is one element if $A has one element.

Comment: No, if $A = \{a\}$, then you must have $x=y=z=a$ snd so $A^3 = \{(a,a,a)\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you have heard of $\mathbb{R}^3$ "the $3$-dimensional space."
It consists of "points" that can be written as $(x,y,z)$ where each of $x,y,z$ is some real number, an element of $\mathbb{R}$. More formally it is the set $\{(x,y,z) \colon x, y , z \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Now, $A^3$ is just the same only that $x,y,z \in A$. Since $A$ is a finite set in your case, you just have a finite number of choices, and you can list them all.

For $A= \{0,a\}$ you can decide for each of $x,y,z$ if it is $a$ or $0$; 
for $A = \{a\}$ you have no real choice at all but must always take $a$.

You could even imagine the first set geometrically. It will give you the vertexes of a cube.

Comment: I understand the A = {a}, but could you go into more detail on A = {0, a}?

Comment: In $A^3$ when $A= \{0,A\}$ you can have $x$ is $0$ or $a$ same for $y$ and $z$. Thus $A^3$ is the set containing $(0,0,0)$, $(a,0, 0)$, $(0, a,0)$ and the $5$ other elements you can construct in this way. Note that for $A= \{a\}$ you just have the element $(a,a,a)$. This is not what you say in the comment on the post.

Answer (score 1):

The **Cartesian Product** is defined in the following way:

> $$A\times B = \{(a,b)~:~a\in A,~b\in B\}$$

That is to say in words, the cartesian product of two sets is the *set of all ordered pairs with first coordinate in the first set and second coordinate in the second set*.

You have likely been using cartesian products since early elementary school without even knowing it.

In our normal $x$-$y$ plane, we commonly refer to a point as $(x,y)$.  The set of all possible points on the $x$-$y$ plane is precisely $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ (which is often shorthanded to be written as $\mathbb{R}^2$)

For finite example, $\{1,2\}\times \{a,b,c\} = \{(1,a),(1,b),(1,c),(2,a),(2,b),(2,c)\}$

In your case, it is a *triple cartesian product* which is defined similarly:

> $$A\times B\times C = \{(a,b,c)~:~a\in A,~b\in B,~c\in C\}$$

In your case, all three sets are the same, and is often shorthanded as being $A\times A\times A=A^3$.

That is to say, in your specific example, the set $A^3$ is the *set of all ordered triples such that every entry is an element of $A$*.

When $A=\{a\}$, how many choices do you have for each entry?  Can you write a list of all possible ordered triples in $A^3$?

When $A=\{0,a\}$, how many choices do you have for each entry?  Can you write a list of all possible ordered triples in $A^3$?